# Error: pgfplots colorbrewer

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, texlive, mac

I am trying to use the new colorbrewer library and get the following error:

> Error: I do not know the key '/pgfplots/colormap/YlOrBr' and I am
>   going to ignore it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[]
    \addplot3[surf, colormap/YlOrBr, samples=41, domain=0:360] {sin(x)*sin(y)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Where is my mistake?

Edit: I previously updated pgfplots to 1.13 with the TexLiveUtility under Mac OS 10.11.3. It tells me now that I have the newest version. Also \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13} does not throw an error.

Comment: This MWE run on my pc without errors, try to update `pgfplots`  package.

Comment: I previously updated pgfplots to 1.13 with the TexLiveUtility under Mac OS 10.11.3. It tells me now that I have the newest version. Also `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}` does not throw an error.

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt, also under MiKTeX 2.9 there is not a problem. Maybe there was something wrong "packed" in your distribution. Do you have the file `pgflibrarypgfplots.colorbrewer.code.tex` in a subfolder of pgfplots? If yes, you should find a line `/pgfplots/colormap/YlOrBr/.style={` in it, which does define the style, right?

Comment: I have
`/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgflibrarypgfplots.colorbrewer.code.tex`
`/usr/local/texlive/2015texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarycolorbrewer.code.tex`
and I found the line you mention in the former.

Comment: Can you copy these files to the folder where your code from the question is and TeX it again. If this works then the files are not correctly "registered" in TeXLive.

Comment: Thx. I copied the files and it works. Any idea how I can "register" it? If make your comments to answer I can accept it.

Comment: Sorry, but I am a MiKTeX only user, but I think that yould be quite easy to google. Because it seems to be a problem with your "specific configuration" I don't think that an answer of mine would be useful for the community. Therefore you hopefully agree that I will flag your question as "off-topic".